# C++ pass reference to function inside same class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, mbed

I am developing an embedded system with the mbed framework in C++.
To attach an interrupt function to the serial interrupt, I normally do this:

```
Serial pc(pin_u_tx, pin_u_rx,115200);

void SerialStart(void) {
...
    pc.attach(&SerInt);
...
}

void SerInt(){
    ...
}
```

But now I need to do the same thing from inside a class, and it doesn't work as I can't refer to an internal function:

```
CTCOMM::CTCOMM()
{
    pc = new Serial(ser_tx, ser_rx, ser_baud);
    pc->attach(&serial_interrupt);
}

void CTCOMM::serial_interrupt() {
...
}
```

I tried a few ways, but none works:

```
pc->attach(&serial_interrupt);
gives the error
lib\CTcomm\ctcomm.cpp:12:17: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&CTCOMM::serial_interrupt' [-fpermissive]

pc->attach(*serial_interrupt);
gives the error
lib\CTcomm\ctcomm.cpp:12:17: error: invalid use of member function 'void CTCOMM::serial_interrupt()' (did you forget the '

pc->attach(*serial_interrupt());
gives the error
lib\CTcomm\ctcomm.cpp:12:33: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be ()' ?)

pc->attach((*this)->*(serial_interrupt));
gives the error
lib\CTcomm\ctcomm.cpp:12:23: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void CTCOMM::serial_interrupt()'
```

and so on (I tried more suggestions found here, but got no succes).
What would be the correct way to point to that function?

Comment: I think you don't have a choice here, as you need a pointer to a function. The only way is to use a static method.

Comment: What is the signature of `attach`? Can you modify it to use, e.g., `std::invoke` to call a callback function? Then you could pass `this` as the first argument to call a member function, something like `attach(&CTCOMM::serial_interrupt, this)`.

Comment: search for "pointer to member function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
`pc->attach(callback(this, &CTCOMM::serial_interrupt));`

`pc->attach(this, &CTCOMM::serial_interrupt);` should also work. But it is deprecated in the recent versions of mbed OS.

Here is the latest Mbed API:
https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.10/mbed-os-api-doxy/classmbed_1_1_serial.html

Comment: First one gives this error:
 `lib\CTcomm\ctcomm.cpp:13:56: error: cannot convert 'CTCOMM*' to 'unsigned char*' in argument passing` but the second one works, only with a warning that it's deprecated! I'll try to fix the first one, but for now thanks, it works.